# Foundation 4 Media Query

Tags: zurb-foundation

I am beginners in CSS designing.

I am using Foundation 4 (Zurb) to design front end of my college project. I learned that Foundation 4 is responsive in nature to design responsive design.

Is there any need of CSS Media query with Foundation 4? If yes then how can I use it what benefit I can get from that?

Answer (score 1):

You should read the "Media-Queries" and "The Grid" sections of the docs:
http://foundation.zurb.com/docs/

```
<div class="row">
  <div id="block" class="small-2 large-8 columns">Content</div>
</div>
```

This code will make "#block" to be 2 columns wide for every screen size due to "small-2" class. The 'large-8' class overrides that behavior on a window width of 768px and above, making it be 8 columns wide on large screens.

To simplify, that code will render "#block" to be 2 columns wide on mobile phone screens and 8 columns on a Desktop Screens.

If you need IE6-8 support, you need to use Respond.js too:
https://github.com/scottjehl/Respond